# I want to flip vertical a div, but not the content inside of it

Tags: css

I'm using -webkit-transform to flip vertical a div, but the problem is that the text inside the div became flipped too... What can i do to flip the div but not the text?

Here is my HTML

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Primer elemento</li>
        <li>Segundo elemento</li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

Here is my CSS

```
div {
    background: lightblue;
    padding-left: 150px;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);  
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

​
And here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uTGXx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the text inside another div which you also flip, as in:

```
<div class="flipped">
    <div class="flipped">
    <ul>
        <li>Primer elemento</li>
        <li>Segundo elemento</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>​
```

where

```
div.flipped {
    background: lightblue;
    padding-left: 150px;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

​See http://jsfiddle.net/uTGXx/2/.